# How do I check if a pixel is empty?

Tags: javascript, image

I am fetching a `.gif`. I need to know if the content-length is `0` or if it’s a 1 × 1 pixel. Is there a way to do this for images via JavaScript?

Comment: `onload` check the width of the image?

Comment: If the content length isn’t `0`, then it’s a 1×1 pixel, right? Are you checking _valid_ GIF files?

Comment: 1x1 pixel image as in: `if(img.width == 1 && img.height == 1){ ... }`?

Comment: What are you trying to archive - I mean, really?! Your title says `pixel is empty`, the content `it's Content-Length: 0` (means the .gif is broken) or `1x1 pixel`. Define empty: transparent pixel, white, black, blue, green on mondays or red on thursdays? [And in the end: what is your final goal?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Image` object to load and check the dimensions before loading it to DOM.

```js
 var img = new Image()
img.src ='http://lorempixel.com//1/1';
img.addEventListener("load", function() {
  console.log(img.naturalWidth)
  console.log(img.naturalHeight)
}, false);

//outputs 1 1
```

Comment: [Image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) constructor accepts width/height (optionallly), not URL.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you.

```js
$('#image').change(function() {
  var img = new Image();

img.onload = function(){
  $('#height').html(img.height);
  $('#width').html(img.width);
};
  img.src = $(this).val();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Image URL: <input type="text" id="image" /></label>

<h1>Width: <span id="width"></span></h1>
<h1>Height: <span id="height"></span></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about looking at gifuct-js https://github.com/matt-way/gifuct-js

it's a gif parser in js.

> The result of the decompressFrames(buildPatch) function returns an array of all the GIF image frames, and their meta data.

You can get the pixel data also

> The pixel data is stored as a list of indexes for each pixel. These each point to a value in the colorTable array, which contain the color that each pixel should be drawn. Each frame of the gif may not be the full size, but instead a patch that needs to be drawn over a particular location. The disposalType defines how that patch should be drawn over the gif canvas. In most cases, that value will be 1, indicating that the gif frame should be simply drawn over the existing gif canvas without altering any pixels outside the frames patch dimensions. More can be read about this here.